# Using apply split() to a column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split values from one column into another.

I'm using apply lambda on the Series

```
df['New_Column']=df['Old_Column'].apply(lambda x: x.split('15')[1])
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I use `split('15')[0]` it runs. So I'm thinking I need it to ignore when there is no '15' in the column?

Comment: You should think about and explain what you really want.  For example, what is the expected output for '1152', '15', '11', '1515', and '115152'.

Comment: Well I need to split 15 °C, 0 and 5 °C, and other strings. I haven't figured out how to include all the ones I need in one condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
df['New_Column'] = df['Old_Column'].str.split('15').str[-1] # if only one  15 in string , it will slice the last position from the right
```

Or `np.where` if more then one 15

```
df['New_Column'] = np.where(df['Old_Column'].str.contains('15'),df['Old_Column'].str.split('15').str[1], df['Old_Column'])
```

Comment: I would leave `1` here when slicing, since there might be more than one 15

Comment: @yatu adding np.where

Comment: What does the [-1] change? And yes is more than one '15', I will have to recreate it for a couple different conditions.

Comment: @Mitch if you only have one 15 when you split the string it will return [xx,xxx] and [-1] slice the last one , so for those who do not have 15 [xx] it will return the original value